# Thingsboard REST api always responds with status 401

Tags: thingsboard

First I got a token using curl command as shown [here](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/#rest-api-auth). Then used this token to authorize swagger and tried some endpoints, but all of them responded with

```
    {
      "status": 401,
      "message": "Authentication failed",
      "errorCode": 10,
      "timestamp": 1490619586352
    }
```

On server side I get this exception:

`2017-03-27 13:31:16,149 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-9] ERROR o.t.s.s.s.m.token.RawAccessJwtToken - Invalid JWT Token io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: Unable to read JSON value: ��!L��ȉ`

I also tried this with curl, with the same results, using this syntax:

`curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'X-Authorization: MY_TOKEN' 'http://MY_SERVER:MY_PORT/api/tenants?limit=3'`

where I changed MY_TOKEN, MY_SERVER and MY_PORT appropriately for my server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that a parameter(Bearer) was missing from one of the headers. It should be `--header 'X-Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN'`. When I added it the responses were as expected. So the complete command for curl is:
`curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'X-Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' 'http://MY_SERVER:MY_PORT/api/tenants?limit=3'`